# Can I profile Lua scripts running in Redis?

Tags: lua, redis, profiling

I have a cluster app that uses a distributed Redis back-end, with dynamically generated Lua scripts dispatched to the redis instances.  The Lua component scripts can get fairly complex and have a significant runtime, and I'd like to be able to profile them to find the hot spots.

SLOWLOG [is useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231698/how-to-determine-the-execution-time-of-a-lua-script-in-redis) for telling me that my scripts are slow, and exactly how slow they are, but that's not my problem.  I know how slow they are, I'd like to figure out which parts of them are slow.

[The redis EVAL docs](http://redis.io/commands/eval) are clear that redis does not export any timekeeping functions to lua, which makes it seem like this might be a lost cause.

So, short a custom fork of Redis, **is there any way to tell which parts of my Lua script are slower than others?**

**EDIT**
I took Doug's suggestion and used debug.sethook - here's the hook routine I inserted at the top of my script:

```
redis.call('del', 'line_sample_count') 
local function profile() 
  local line = debug.getinfo(2)['currentline'] 
  redis.call('zincrby', 'line_sample_count', 1, line) 
end 
debug.sethook(profile, '', 100)
```

Then, to see the hottest 10 lines of my script:

```
ZREVRANGE line_sample_count 0 9 WITHSCORES
```

Comment: Look at this Redis-wrecker that I made: https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-lua-debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scripts are processing bound (not I/O bound), then you may be able to use the [`debug.sethook`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.sethook) function with a count hook:

> The **count hook**: is called after the interpreter executes every
>   count instructions. (This event only happens while Lua is executing a
>   Lua function.)

You'll have to build a profiler based on the counts you receive in your callback.

The [PepperfishProfiler](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PepperfishProfiler) would be a good place to start. It uses `os.clock` which you don't have, but you could just use hook counts for a very crude approximation.

This is also covered in [PiL 23.3 – Profiles](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.3.html)

Comment: This sent me down the right path - at least as close as I think I'm going to be able to get with the restrictions Redis requires.  I'll edit my question with the profiling hook I came up with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In standard Lua C, you can't. It's not a built-in function - it only returns seconds. So, there are two options available: You either write your own Lua extension DLL to return the time in msec, or:

You can do a basic benchmark using a millisecond-resolution time. You can access the current millisecond time with LuaSocket. Though this adds a dependency to your project, it's an effective way to do trivial benchmarking.

```
require "socket"
t = socket.gettime();
```

Comment: The Lua script is running inside a Redis server. The only libraries I can use are : base, table, string, math, debug, cjson, and cmsgpack.

Comment: Ah. The only way I can think of is to manually add libraries. It's open source. It would be a pain, though. I'm surprised you can't add your own libraries.

Comment: The limitation on timekeeping functions is purposeful - you can't even call the builtin time function, because that would break the guarantee of deterministic execution required for the redis-cluster implementation.

Comment: Can you attach your own libraries as Lua addons in DLL form?

Comment: I'd have to recompile Redis and link them in statically - not out of the question, but I'd like to see if there's an easy button first...

Comment: @Drew Alright, I'll leave this answer here as a placeholder. I hope there's an easier way, though.