# get current date and time in lua in redis

Tags: lua, redis

How can I get current date / time in Lua embedded in Redis?

I need to have it in following format - YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MM:SS

Tried with os.date() but it does not recognize it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Redis' Lua sandbox has only a handful of libraries, and `os` isn't one of these.

You can call the Redis [`TIME`](http://redis.io/commands/time) from Lua like so:

```
local t = redis.call('TIME')
```

However, you'll need to find a way to convert the epoch to the desired format and also note that it will stop you script from performing any writes (as it is a non-deterministic command).

Update: as of Redis v3.2, there is a new replication mode for scripts that is effect-based (rather than code-based). When using this mode you can actually call all the random, non-deterministic commands. More information is at [`EVAL`'s documentation page](https://redis.io/commands/eval)

Comment: That's really surprise me :) never knew there is a time command

Comment: thanks to mentioned about "non-deterministic command" - this really will hurt the script. I guess I will pass date from the parameter list

Comment: That's **exactly** how you should do it ;)

Comment: This answer does not answer the question since there is no easy way to convert timestamp to date.

Answer (score 6):

This was already discussed in the comments, but the correct answer should have an answer:

The current time is non-deterministic i.e. it returns different values on repeated calls. This hurts replication. For this reason, the current time should be passed into your LUA script as a parameter.